# Change Mesh Color On Button Press THREE js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Iam Trying To Change The Colour Of A Sphere Mesh when A Button Is Pressed with three js But Can't seem To Get It Working whenever i use mesh.material.color.SetHex() with a Click event listner it doesn't work. However Whenever I use It Outside The Eventlistner It works Just Fine Here is My Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="propertiesPanel">
        <p>Properties Panel</p>
        <p>Albedo Colour</p>
        <input type="text" id="albedo">
        <button id="btn">Change</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerWidth, 0.1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 5;
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});

        renderer.setClearColor("#4b4b4b");
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        })


        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 20, 20);
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFFCC00});
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        scene.add(mesh);
        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            mesh.material.color.setHex( 0xc24a4a );});


        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 500);
        light.position.set(10, 0, 25);
        scene.add(light);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't render over and over, meaning that the color of your sphere might be changed, but the 'new' sphere isn't being displayed. Put this at the end of you code:

```
function render(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(render)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}
render();
```

The rest of your code should work fine.